# 2d-Array fails when trying to populate

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am writing a class that eventually will solve the 8-Queen puzzle. I added a test method named populate, to make sure i am creating the 2d array correctly and dynamically allocating memory correctly, however when this method is called the program crashes, when i debug the following Visual studio error pops up:

```
Exception thrown at 0x01281DFB in 8Queen.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCDCDCDCD.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

my constructor:

```
Queen::Queen(int s)
{
    size = s;
    board = new int *[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        board[size] = new int[size];
}
```

my populate method:

```
void Queen::populate()

    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)  // for each row
            for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) // for each column
                board[i][j] = 1;
    }
```

my deconstruct:

```
Queen::~Queen()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        delete[] board[i];

    delete[] board;
}
```

my main:

```
int main()
{
    fm::Queen board(10);

    board.populate();
    board.printBoard();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what? does this work fine for you?

Comment: well in debugger i do get that error, i can post the full code

Comment: Try to create a [mcve] that reproduces the error and update your question with the complete code.

Comment: THIS CODE DOES PRODUCE my problem in my pc once the code reaches populating, in the first pass of loop i get this error

Comment: Stop using manual memory management... then you can spend your time actually implementing logic for solving the queen problem, instead of mucking around with memory errors and access violations

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<int>> board(size, std::vector<int>(size));` -- No error, and you don't have a memory leak if any of those calls to `new[]` throw an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your constructor, you have the following line:

```
board[size] = new int[size];
```

Likely, you want this to be

```
board[i] = new int[size];
```

Comment: you are correct problem solved, i dont know why i put that there, thank you. I can pick your answer in 3 min